# Group by query advise

Tags: sql, sql-server

In sql server, i am having a table with product as below

```
Manf    Prod    Id  Desc
Audi    A1  1   Tyre tye 1
Audi    A1  2   Tyre type 2
Audi    A1  3   Tyre type 3
BMW     B1  4   Tyre tye 1
BMW     B1  5   Tyre type 2
BMW     B1  6   Tyre type 3
Toyota  T1  7   Tyre type 1
```

I want to output with  group by  columns of manf and prod but id should be any of values.. Kindly advise the query..

```
Manf    Prod    Id
Audi    A1      1
BMW     B1      4
Toyota  T1      7
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select Manf, Prod, min(id) as Id
from your_table
group by Manf, Prod
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a complete row, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by manf, prod order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      form table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```